# Select query execution from php missing on record

Tags: php, mysql

I am pulling my hair from last hour. Two queries one is direcly running on mysql result is fine but from php it is missing one record .  I don't know why?
in php

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM switch_person WHERE Half = ".$half." AND EmployeeNamePK = ".$pk." AND SwitchDate = CURDATE() order by PTPK";
echo "<br>".$sql."<br>";
$outputArray = array();
$result =  mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());
while($emp = mysql_fetch_assoc(($result))){
    $outputArray[] = $emp["PTPK"];
    echo $emp["PTPK"],"</br>",$emp["PK"],"</br>";
}
```

in sql

```
SELECT * FROM switch_person WHERE Half = 2 AND 
      EmployeeNamePK = 2 AND SwitchDate = CURDATE() order by PTPK
```

Comment: Where are you setting / initializing `$half` and `$pk` ?  Have you made sure they are correct in the php version?

Comment: The query constructed in PHP looks fine. What are the data types of `Half`, `EmployeeNamePK`.

Comment: Which record is it missing? Is it the first?

Comment: Are you sure you copied the code exactly. I've seen lots of questions where they had an extra call to `mysql_fetch_assoc()` before the loop, and that caused the loop to miss the first record.

Comment: @Barmar last record!

Comment: @Epodax yeah i have echo the query as well! and same query run on mysql directly

Comment: Can you show the data on database?

Comment: Is the row missing in `var_dump($outputArray)`?

Comment: Are you sure you're accessing the same database, not a test DB?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I've copied your script in my editor and i noticed that the first double quote Half = -->"<--.$half." is fault. You have a Curly quote there. Its hard to see. delete that and replace it with a regular straight double quote. I dont know if its stackoverflow that is showing it like that or your code. Also try it with single quotes to ensure if thats the fault or not.

Also i recommend using PDO